# How to overcome (Fedora-38) vs-code dies on launch?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, fedora

After a couple of dnf updates, code now dies on launch with...

```
$ code --verbose
[2270098:0920/003958.296920:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:58.374Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /home/mike/.config/Code/User (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>),/home/mike/.config/Code/User/settings.json (excludes: <none>, includes: <all>)
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:58.384Z] Sending env to running instance...
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:58.384Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/mike/.config/Code/User'
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:58.385Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/mike/.config/Code/User/settings.json'
[2270137:0920/003958.432675:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[2270137:0920/003958.442280:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[2270137:0920/003958.442489:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
...
[2270137:0920/003958.447300:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(255)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:59.374Z] Sent env to running instance. Terminating...
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:59.375Z] Lifecycle#kill()
[main 2023-09-20T07:39:59.375Z] Lifecycle#onWillShutdown.fire()
```

It was running locally and remotely over SSH a week ago.  I can't find any protection issues.  How can I get past that?

Answer (score 0):

This error should be handled more gracefully, but I discovered that the vs-code application windows were somehow starting minimized, invisible because one taskbar icon was gathering all of them together.  I had about ten of them before I looked at what that single taskbar icon was actually representing.  I closed the ones I didn't need.  Immediate problem solved.